# Custom response using springboot rest

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm developing RestAPI using springboot 2.0.0. I'd like to customize the response for all RestAPI calls.

API URL : http://localhost:8080/api/contacts and result is

```
{
   "content":[
      {
         "id":10,
         "name":"raj",
      },
   ],
   "pageable":{
      "sort":{
         "sorted":false,
         "unsorted":true
      },
      "offset":0,
      "pageSize":10,
      "pageNumber":0,
      "paged":true,
      "unpaged":false
   },
   "last":true,
   "totalPages":1,
   "totalElements":1,
   "size":10,
   "number":0,
   "numberOfElements":1,
   "first":true,
   "sort":{
      "sorted":false,
      "unsorted":true
   }
}
```

How I'd like to customize is, JSON key *content* must be replaced with last part of the relative path of RestAPI. In this case **content** replaced with *contacts* and also How do I customize pageable json in response?

I'm returning org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable<Entity>

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the arrangement of the fields in your custom entity.

Comment: can't get your answer, Let me explain what I'm doing and what I need
Controller


    @GetMapping
    ResponseEntity<Example<?>> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
      return exampleService.gets(pageable);
    }

this snippet returns the above json, now what I need is
move those pageable response meta json
and rename the content to last part of the relative path of RestAPI